# won't save, file size to large

Tags: json, mongodb, upload, openshift, yeoman

Okay so I've got an `MEAN` application on `Openshift` and I have been adding a lot to the database. Then suddenly I get the error that the file is too large from my API.

Okay I think, maybe the database is just full. So I go in and adds 5GB storage to the Mongo gear. Then I go back and want to continue my work... Same problem.

I can add a small text, and then nothing at all. And it should be added that I, before this error, were able to add even larger files to my database.

What can the problem be and how can I check it and fix it.

Some of the informations I can gather from trying to `SSH` my application.

```
[ my application ]\> quota
Disk quotas for user 55e********************** (uid 3***):
 Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
/dev/mapper/EBSStore01-user_home01
             104668       0 6291456            9752       0  480000
```

```
db.stats()
{
    "db" : "admin",
    "collections" : 3,
    "objects" : 7,
    "avgObjSize" : 67.42857142857143,
    "dataSize" : 472,
    "storageSize" : 16384,
    "numExtents" : 3,
    "indexes" : 2,
    "indexSize" : 16352,
    "fileSize" : 16777216,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "dataFileVersion" : {
            "major" : 4,
            "minor" : 5
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've just tried to make write the `rhc app-show <app name> --gears quota` command and this is my result

```
User@pc ~/dist/.git (GIT_DIR!)
$ rhc app-show unityacademy --gears quota
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Unable to connect to gear (gear id)
Unable to connect to gear (gear id)
Gear                     Cartridges               Used  Limit
------------------------ ----------------------- ----- ------
(gear id)                mongodb-2.4             error 6.4 GB
(gear id)                haproxy-1.4 nodejs-0.10 error 6.4 GB
```

From what I can see here there should be plety of storage to be used. Or am I ready these numbers incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, of sorts, I changed some of my code to downsize some of the object from my database, which solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is scaled (used multiple gears), try running the 'rhc app show  --gears quota' command, it is possible that your web gear is out of disk space, not your mongodb gear, and that is preventing the upload into a temporary holding space before the file/data is inserted into mongodb.

Comment: Just updated my question. I tried your solution. I get an error which prevents me from seeing the used amount. And I've tried to fix that error before without success. However, I've added an additional 5GB to the gears after I got the initial problem, which haven't fixed the problem :'-(

Comment: Can you use the contact form at https://developers.openshift.com/contact and include a link to this question along with your username & application url and we will look into the issue.